# Add dash in between each td selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**What I am trying to achieve**

I wrote a simple *copy to clipboard* function, where when you click on a table row it will take the contents of cell child 2,3 and 4 and copy to the clipboard. **But** also add a dash in between the content.

**Example**

```
Raw data: 123456789
Copied data: 123-456-789
```

**My problem**

I cannot seem to add a dash in between. I got a `.find` but cannot add a dash between each `td` selector. Is it possible to add just raw text to it? Or would I need to seperate `.find` and add a dash in between or something with `.text` into three? Most elegant solution would just to be to add the `-` inside the only `.find`?

**What my working copy to clipboard looks like:**

```
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).find('td:eq(2), td:eq(3), td:eq(4)').text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
```

`Output: 123456789`

**What I would assumely want to achieve:**

```
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).find('td:eq(2), "-" td:eq(3), "-" td:eq(4)').text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}

Desired output: 123-456-789
```

The closest I have gotten is this

`.find("td:eq(2), td:eq(3), td:eq(4)").append("-").text()).select();`

But that adds a dash at the end and ALSO manipulates the DOM which is not something I want. Therefore using `.append` is off the table.

```
Output: 123-456-789-
```

Comment: Maybe ```.find("td:eq(2), td:eq(3), td:eq(4)").text().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1-');```

Comment: @weroro Elegant solution, works the way intended. However you're really dependent on having a static amount of digits in each cell. Luckily that is the case for me, but for others having the same problem may not. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve, I've decided to add all `innerText` values to an array using [jQuery.map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) and the [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). Then [.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array using the `-` as separator.

`const res = [...$("td:eq(2), td:eq(3), td:eq(4)").map((i, e) => e.innerText)].join("-");`

**Full Solution:**

```js
$(function() {
    $("#copy-to-clipboard").on("click", copyToClipboard);

    function copyToClipboard() {
        var $temp = $("<input>");
        $("body").append($temp);
        const res = [...$("td:eq(2), td:eq(3), td:eq(4)").map((i, e) => e.innerText)].join("-");
        $temp.val(res).trigger("select");
        document.execCommand("copy");
        $temp.remove();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="copy-to-clipboard">Copy To Clipboard</button>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>321</td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>456</td>
        <td>789</td>
        <td>987</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input type="text" placeholder="Paste here to test">
```

Comment: Ideal solution, Gary. I am surprised there wasn't a easier fix to for this but using `.map` and `innerText` to just add a single `-`. Anyways, thanks for the help. I've decided to use this solution as it doesn't rely on the content of the cells  to be static in form of amount of digits but the actual DOM.

Comment: Also to help future viewers; mind creating an example baked with my question's code? That way this question can be improved even more and comprehendable for everyone. Answer accepted as solution.